# wordpress url structure

Tags: wordpress, url, categories

Is it possible in wordpress when I call `example.com/category` to have listed all available categories. If I request the url like in my example I'm getting an 404 page

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is the place you're looking for - and don't forget to search first for a similar question before asking :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a default link to list all the categories.

But it doesn't mean you can't do it yourself. Create a new template file in your theme, name it for example **category_list.php** and add this code:

You might want to tweak it a bit to display it how you want.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Category listing
 * Description: list all the categories
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?php
        $args=array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $categories=get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category):
            echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
            echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
            echo '<hr />'; 
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then go to Pages -> add new. Name the Page as "Category", so that the url will be `example.com/category`.

And in the template list select the template you just created. It will be named "Category listing" as you can see in the code above in the comments at the top.